# Sulu.io CMS editor add images inside content

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, content-management-system, sulu

Is there a way to add images inside Sulu.io editor, rather than creating properties or blocks?

I have been searching this in their issues, documentation and google, but I'm not sure if its possible or not, even tho one can add image links but not image tag, does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't plan to support putting images directly into the editor. We actually also don't want that, because it contradicts our philosophy. Enabling the user to do stuff like that in the editor, would probably also allow him to break the site in unexpected ways, and it's close to impossible to properly implement a responsive design this way.